# 2 domains SEO link building

Tags: seo, google, multiple-domains, link-building

I have 2 domains: `www.my-domain.co` and `www.mydomain.us`.

Both are pointing for the same server, for example if you run `www.my-domain.co/file.html`, it's the same with `www.mydomain.us/file.html`.

Now ... I began the SEO for `www.my-domain.co`, submitted in Webmaster Tools, sitemap, links etc. I supposed `www.my-domain.co` will rank good for *my domain* keywords. After 1 year I change the domain from Webmaster Tools to `www.mydomain.us` which has no links pointed to him, and now the question come:

If I begin the link building (dofollow blogs, formus, link directories etc.) once more on `www.mydomain.us` it will get double link juice?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll get is duplicate content issues. That's not good. You need to choose which domain is your primary and do a 301 redirect from the secondary domain to the primary domain. Then you should solely seek links to your primary domain. But if someone points a link to your secondary domain it will count towards your primary domain with only a small dampening factor. This also applies to existing links so if you do switch domains the old links will still help you (minus the dampening factor).

Comment: so what are you saying is that i must hurry up changing domains, because this is bad ... and i must admit, i have not ranked good for over 2-3 month for now ... i dont know what to do ...

Comment: @Row Minds Just do a 301 redirect from your .co domain to your .us domain and do SEO for the .us domain if you want to see the .us domain as your new primary domain.